# bootstrap CSS não carrega quando a aplicação é publicada no IIS

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, iis

Quando estou executando a aplicação no visual studio 2010 eu não tenho problema com o boostrap CSS e o javascript, porém, quando eu a publico no IIS, todo os javascripts e os css's não são reconhecidos.
Eu criei uma página simples em html para testar se é um problema de formatação do html, mas o problema ainda acontece. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>
                Bootstrap starter template</h1>
            <p class="lead">
                Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br>
                All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                Ok</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia fornecer detalhes do erro que aparece no console (aba network) do navegador, é um pouco amplo

Comment: o problema era o MIME Type do CSS no IE. Já foi resolvido.

Comment: Thiago se foi resolvido formule uma resposta como solução, não somos um fórum de suporte, somo um Q&A (pergunas e respostas), recomendo que leia o [Help](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 2):

O problema era que, no MIME Type do ISS do site, estava setado "text/csss" para arquivos .css. Achei curioso que o problema ocorre para arquivos css's do boostrap e não ocorre para outros arquivos css. Porém, alterando para "text/css" o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score -3):

tive o mesmo problema
no meu caso foi ao ativar o IIS, e seus componentes

https://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp6Y1.png)

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)